# Help on multiple inner join query

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have this query

```
SELECT t1.Trans_ID
FROM (SELECT * FROM Prune WHERE [Name]="I1")  AS t1 
INNER JOIN (SELECT * FROM Prune WHERE [Name]="I2")  AS t2 ON (t1.Trans_ID = t2.Trans_ID)
INNER JOIN (SELECT * FROM Prune WHERE [Name]="I3")  AS t3 ON (t1.Trans_ID = t3.Trans_ID)
```

and i got error msg : " Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression

```
'(t1.Trans_ID = t2.Trans_ID)
INNER JOIN (SELECT * FROM Prune WHERE [Name]="I3")  AS t3 ON (t1.Trans_ID = t3.Trans_ID)'
```

But that query work perfectly when i'm using only 1 inner join

```
SELECT t1.Trans_ID
FROM (SELECT * FROM Prune WHERE [Name]="I1")  AS t1 
INNER JOIN (SELECT * FROM Prune WHERE [Name]="I2")  AS t2 ON (t1.Trans_ID = t2.Trans_ID)
```

anyone can tell what happen? and how to solve it?
I'm working with ms access

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*MsAccess is sometimes full of shit...*

Try this

```
SELECT t1.Trans_ID 
FROM ((SELECT * FROM Prune WHERE [Name]="I1")  AS t1  
INNER JOIN (SELECT * FROM Prune WHERE [Name]="I2")  AS t2 ON (t1.Trans_ID = t2.Trans_ID))
INNER JOIN (SELECT * FROM Prune WHERE [Name]="I3")  AS t3 ON (t1.Trans_ID = t3.Trans_ID)
```

Please note the additional open bracket **just** after `FROM`  and additional closing bracket **just** after `t2.Trans_ID)`

Comment: can't say more :D msaccess is indeed full of #####, Thank you.

Comment: This took me some time to figure out previously, as I am more of a Sql Server guy X-)

Comment: I you people would accustom yourselves to using the QBE to write your joins for you, you'd have a lot less problem with this kind of thing.

Comment: And then some day, when you grow older, and you need to write more complex queries in a different database (Sql Server) you will appreciate the fact that you can write queries by hand X-)

Comment: "MsAccess is sometimes full of shit..."  , really agree with it

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
SELECT t1.Trans_ID
FROM Prune AS t1
INNER JOIN Prune AS t2 ON t1.Trans_ID = t2.Trans_ID
INNER JOIN Prune AS t3 ON t1.Trans_ID = t3.Trans_ID
WHERE t1.Name = "I1" AND t2.Name = "I2" AND t3.Name = "I3"
```